# App crashes if I set delegate and datasource of tableview

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

Hi I added an `UITableView` in my app (storyboard) with a custom cell.
Now I wanted to add the delegate and datasource programmatically. If add this code in `viewDidLoad` the app crashes.

```
   tableView.delegate = self
   tableView.dataSource = self
```

Error:

```
2016-01-30 16:39:29.283 App[4068:880212] Unknown class TableCell in Interface Builder file.
2016-01-30 16:39:29.289 App[4068:880212] *** Terminating app due to  uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UITableViewCell 0x7fa3a356bb10> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imgTeam1.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105302e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000107042deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105302aa9 -[NSException raise] + 9
3   Foundation                          0x00000001056cb9bb -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 288
4   UIKit                               0x0000000105bd5fd9 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) setValue:forKey:] + 173
5   UIKit                               0x0000000105edcf41 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001052434a0 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
7   UIKit                               0x0000000105edb924 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864
8   UIKit                               0x0000000105c654f7 -[UITableView _dequeueReusableViewOfType:withIdentifier:] + 428
9   App                                 0x0000000105112cd9 _TFC6App14ViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 233
10  App                                 0x00000001051134ff _TToFC6App14ViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 79
11  UIKit                               0x0000000105c78e43 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 766
12  UIKit                               0x0000000105c78f7b -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
13  UIKit                               0x0000000105c4da39 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2996
14  UIKit                               0x0000000105c8201c -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 92
15  UIKit                               0x0000000105c68edc -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 224
16  UIKit                               0x0000000105bd64a3 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a08859a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a07ce70 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
19  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a07ccee _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a071475 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
21  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a09ec0a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
22  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a09f37c _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010522e367 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010522e2d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010522384c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
26  UIKit                               0x0000000105b1a7cd -[UIApplication _run] + 402
27  UIKit                               0x0000000105b1f610 UIApplicationMain + 171
28  App                                 0x000000010511567d main + 109
29  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000107b4b92d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I hope your know how to fix this.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I added the error in my question.

Comment: You should be giving feedback on the answers below. Doing so will help us to discover a solution that will assist you. If you participate more then people will take time to help you. Just add comments if the solutions are helpful and vote. If the solutions do not help fix the problem then share more details about the issue. The more you participate the better the Q&A process will be for you.

Comment: I got it fixed by adding the tableview programmatically. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you deleted `@IBOutlet weak var imgTeam1: UIImageView!` (or renamed it) but still connected in the interface builder. You need to add the property again or delete it from the view.

Answer (score 0):

- It is not fault of data source & delegate ,check for outlet
  `imgTeam1` connected correctlty.
- The outlets in the custom cell in `StoryBoard` must be connected to the Custom
  cell class property
- One more thing to add ,instead of setting datasource & delegate in
  code set in the `StoryBoard`.

Comment: I deleted and reset all outlets from storyboard to TableCell.swift. I can't add the delegate & data source on storyboard. Don't know why. The TableView can't be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

you might delete or miss connection to the delegate imgTeam1 from xib

Answer (score 0):

The answers given thus far are correct. This one simply shows how to take corrective action. You need to select your orange controller on your storyboard for the class where the error occurs. Then select the connections inspector. Find the key mentioned in the error line:

`2016-01-30 16:39:29.289 App[4068:880212] *** Terminating app due to  uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UITableViewCell 0x7fa3a356bb10> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imgTeam1.'`

Then click the `x` next to the key mentioned in the error message. This will clear the error.

If you want to be sure you do not have any further error messages regarding the TableView delegate and datastore just verify whether they already have a connection on the connections inspector. If the delegate/datastore already have a connection on the storyboard then you will not need to add the connections in code.

Just FYI, If you use a UITableViewController, then you will get the delegate/datastore and tableView connections all setup automatically with no need to add anything in code. If you are using a UIViewController with a manually added tableView then you will need to setup the connections for the tableView, delegate, and datastore manually. The delegate/datastore can also be set using the storyboard by control dragging from the connections inspector to the orange view controller.

[image: connections-inspector]